# SQL current system date

Tags: mysql, sql, jsp, date, sqlyog

I have a query to store current system date by calling the [`sysdate`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_sysdate) [date-time function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html). But it is giving me error that your sql syntax is not correct. Here is the query

> ```
> insert into mtc (entryDate) values TO_DATE(sysdate,'fmyyyy-mm-dd');
> ```
>
> I have tried this below query it worked properly but in DB it stores 0000-00-00
>   insert into mtc (entryDate) values ('sysdate');

As i am using SQLyog, its date format is yyyy-mm-dd. Further, i have to use this query in my jsp code. What will be its syntax in jsp ?

Kind regards.

Comment: You're missing parentheses from `SYSDATE()`, and `SYSDATE` default format is `yyyy-mm-dd` so that part probably isn't needed.

Comment: yes it was the mistake . Thanks @Garry !

Comment: Glad to help, if it's okay with you I'll add it as an answer for acceptance so future users can find easily (and so I get the points!).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing parentheses from SYSDATE(), and SYSDATE default format is yyyy-mm-dd so that part probably isn't needed.

Comment: I was not sure that it was just a mistake of parenthesis. But is was actually. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: That's probably best asked as a new question for the sake of future users.